# How can I upload a PDF file into database using online database using php

Tags: php, file-upload

I followed a tutorial and the code below is for inserting images in database. I want to upload a PDF file instead of an image.
With the code I don't know what to change in order to insert a PDF file into database. I found another tutorial with location. I also want to allow users to upload the PDFs in any location/folder.

`upload.php`:

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Success</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
    <label>Anouncement</label>
    </div>
   <div class="aa">
    <div class="vertical-menu">
    <img src="abc.png" class="img-circle" alt="Ice" width="200" height="200" id="ice">
    <h2 align="center">Milagros Quanico</h2>
    <h3 align="center"><?php
   $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id834551_teacherss";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "id834551_teacher";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    $conn->close();


    ?></h3>

        <i><a align="center" class="active" href="welcome.php">Home</a></i>
        <i><a align="center" href="Add1.php">Update Topics</a></i>
        <i><a align="center" href="calendar1.php">Calendar</a></i>
        <i><a align="center" href="db.php">#View</a></i>
        <i><a align="center" href="logout.php">Log out</a></i>
        <br><br><br></br></br></br>
    </div>
    <div class="dd"> <!--Content-->
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1>Welcome Users </h1>   

<?php
$msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
   if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
   {
    echo "Please Select an image.";
   }
   else {
    $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image = file_get_contents($image);
    $image = base64_encode($image);
    saveimage($name,$image);
   }
}
displayimage();
function saveimage($name,$image)
{
$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id834551_teacherss";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "id834551_teacher";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (name,images) values ('$name','$image')";
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($result) {
        echo "<br/> Image uploaded.";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br/> Image not uploaded.";
    }
}
function displayimage()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id834551_teacherss";
    $password = "jeromelim";
    $dbname = "id834551_teacher";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<img height ="300" width ="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

}
   ?>


    <form method = "post" action = "uploads.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <input type = "hidden" name ="size" value = "1000000">
    <div>
        <input type = "file" name = "image"/>
    </div>                    
    <div>
        <textarea name = "text" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Say Something Here">

        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type = "submit" name="upload" value="Upload File">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>        
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is the actual code that the image being insert onto database. and i want to upload also the pdf file

```js
<?php
$msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
   if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
   {
    echo "Please Select an image.";
   }
   else {
    $image = addslashes($_FILES[''])
    $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image = file_get_contents($image);
    $image = base64_encode($image);
    saveimage($name,$image);
   }
}
displayimage();
function saveimage($name,$image)
{
$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id834551_teacherss";
    $password = "jeromelim";
    $dbname = "id834551_teacher";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (name,images) values ('$name','$image')";
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($result) {
        echo "<br/> Image uploaded.";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br/> Image not uploaded.";
    }
}
function displayimage()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id834551_teacherss";
    $password = "jeromelim";
    $dbname = "id834551_teacher";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<img height ="300" width ="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

}
   ?>
```

Comment: You upload and store a PDF exactly the same as you upload and store an image. You use exactly the same code. The only difference is the filename. What problem are you having?

Comment: You already have a functional form upload. Are you only having issue **displaying** the uploaded PDF? You're echoing out an `<img>` tag, which is why that part isn't working as you'd expect.

Comment: when im using this code. the error say please select an image

Comment: @jerome That is not an error, that is just the statements run when `if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)` condition is fulfilled.. In this case `getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])` will return false since the provided file is not an image.. Try getting rid this condition

Comment: so what should i do thiis

Answer (score 1):

Code updated ...

```
 <?php
$msg = "";

$tmp_file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
if($tmp_file){

      $img_name=basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
      $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($img_name, "."), 1));
      $ext1=".".$ext;

      $allowed = array('.pdf');

      if(in_array($ext1, $allowed)){

      // Update Path to upload on server

      $img_path="";
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,$img_path);
      saveiFILE($img_name,$img_path);


     }else{
         $output_message="Uploaded File seems to be Undefined Type";
     }

}
function saveFILE($name,$image)
{
$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id834551_teacherss";
    $password = "jeromelim";
    $dbname = "id834551_teacher";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (name,images) values ('$name','$image')";
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($result) {
        echo "<br/> fILE uploaded.";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br/> SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
    }
}
   ?>
```

Comment: and also i want let the user to upload in any file like my code above i let the user to choose in any file they want

Comment: Could you tell me , What is your actual query ? I'll do update the code with your code. Do you want to upload pdf and want to save the file name to Database ?  Am i right !

Comment: i updated my above code. yes you are right im going to save the pdf into database

Comment: Is there any need of function DisplayImage ? If you upload an PDF then that Function will not work with PDF file .

Comment: There are two ways to save PDF in Database ... 1) upload and save pdf on server And Save PATH of pdf to DB  ......... 2) upload and Save pdf as BLOBs ... Which way you prefer ?

Comment: i think the way of 1 save pdf and path to db

Comment: the answer above undefined image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777479/how-can-i-upload-a-pdf-file-on-php-with-file-path-and-url